# jquery tab is not working in safari ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I am working on the application, everything is working fine, but when i am testing it on multiple devices it's not working properly.
In desktop and Android mobile and or android tab result is fine.
But the problem is it's not showing the tab container(data) in IOS.
Please help me thanks.

Please see the below screen so u can understand better.

[image]

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: no console errors there.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this could be found by plugging you iOS device into a Mac and using the web inspector from the Mac to remotely investigate the problem. Without a link to your website or more information about the html and css it is very hard for us to give you any other possible solutions.

Comment: yes, i find something. When i add another jquery simple tab design on it. It's showing the content but scripting is not working, is there any other way to use jquery or javascript to use in IOS.